# C program directory scanner only working for one directory

Tags: c, file, directory, coredump

my code here suppose to scan a directory for all the .wor files, and extract info from each file to a new .csv file.
However, it only works for one directory ( the directory i am writing this c program in, which has 2 .wor files and a few text files).  When I try to enter a different directory with just 3 .wor files in it, it gives me a the error message i assigned it to display when the file==NULL; from this line:

```
     if (fs == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Cannot open source file");

        return 1;
    }
```

if i remove this if statement all together, it displays a "bus error(Core dump)" error.

I am not sure what is going on, is there something i am not doing here?

Here is my complete code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <dirent.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <errno.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv) {

char directory[100];
char buff[100];
char delims[] = " :=";
char *result = NULL;
char *customer;
char *device;
char *testprog;
char *software;
char *dutboardid;
char *corlbox;
int i=0;
DIR * FD;
struct dirent* in_file;
int c=0;

/*printf ("Enter directory:");                                   
    scanf ("%s",directory);*/


    FILE * ft = fopen ( "workorderlist.csv", "w" ) ;    /* Open file to write to*/
    if ( ft == NULL )
    {
           puts ( "Cannot open target file" ) ;
           exit( 1 ) ;
    }

    fprintf (ft, "Work Order,Customer,Device,Test_Prog,Software,DUT_board_id,Corl box\n");



/* Open Directory*/

if (NULL == (FD = opendir ("/home/iselabs/dwang/pinscale/workorder/practice"))) 
    {

        puts ("Cannot open directory");

    return 1;
    }


    while ((in_file = readdir(FD))) 
    {

    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
        continue;
    if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))    
        continue;


    /* Open files to read from  */



size_t len = strlen(in_file->d_name);
if (len >= 4 && memcmp(in_file->d_name + len - 4, ".wor", 4) == 0)   /* checks if file ends with .wor */
{

FILE * fs = fopen(in_file->d_name, "r");       /* open file to read */

    if (fs == NULL)
    {
        puts ("Cannot open source file");

        return 1;
    }

    /* Scanning each file for targeted words: */


while( fgets(buff, 100,fs) != NULL )      
{   
 result = strtok( buff, delims );          
    while(result != NULL){                   
            if((strcmp(result,"Customer")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }


            if((strcmp(result,"name")==0)){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        customer = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(customer, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(customer)+1;i++){ if(customer[i] == '\n') break; }
        customer[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"device")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        device = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(device, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(device)+1;i++){ if(device[i] == '\n') break; } 
        device[i] = ' ';
        }


            if(strcmp(result,"test_prog")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        testprog = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(testprog, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(testprog)+1;i++){ if(testprog[i] == '\n') break; } 
        testprog[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"Rev")==0 || strcmp(result,"use")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

        if(strcmp(result,"rev")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        software = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(software, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(software)+1;i++){ if(software[i] == '\n') break; } 
        software[i] = ' ';
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"DUT_board_id")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        dutboardid = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dutboardid, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(dutboardid)+1;i++){ if(dutboardid[i] == '\n') break; } 
        dutboardid[i] = ' ';
        }                   
        else if (strcmp(result,"DUT_board_id")==1){
        corlbox = "N/A";
        }

            if(strcmp(result,"box")==0){ 
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);  
        corlbox = (char*)malloc((strlen(result)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(corlbox, result);
        for(i=0;i<strlen(corlbox)+1;i++){ if(corlbox[i] == '\n') break; } 
        corlbox[i] = ' ';
        }
        else if (strcmp(result,"box")==1){
        corlbox = "N/A";
        }           
        result = strtok(NULL,delims);
    }

}


fprintf (ft, "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n", in_file->d_name, customer, device, testprog, software, dutboardid, corlbox);


printf(in_file->d_name);
printf("\n");
fclose (fs) ;
c++;

}
}
printf("Total Workorders Found: %d \n", c);
    fclose ( ft ) ;
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You may not have permissions to open/read files in that directory.

Comment: I should, it is a directory i created in my own folder, just like the other directory that is working.  Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Oh and i wrote a program before that reads the files individually, and it works for both directories.  So i am pretty sure i have permissions to open/read the files in both directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the directory name with the filename that you're trying to open, or possibly call `chdir()` before trying to open the file.

You could `malloc` a buffer based on the combined length of the directory name, plus filename, plus an extra character for the path separator (`/`) and one more for the null terminator.

Then use `sprintf( buffer, "%s/%s", directory, filename);` to get the full path to the file, and then try to open that.

Add a `printf` to your error string, with the name of the file you're trying to open, to help with debugging.

Comment: Yup; you need to create the full pathname.  The code in [How to use `readdir()` to make array of file names?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14191292/15168) illustrates one way of doing it.

Comment: Awsome.  That is indeed the problem.  Thank you.